# Is it possible to configure a blank line at the bottom of a gnome terminal?

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

When the terminal text reaches the bottom of the window, it's hard to see underscores and font descenders since they're so close to the window border.

Can I configure a blank line (or 2)?

Answer (score 0):

You could output the **terminal control codes** ("ANSI codes:, "xterm control codes") to **go one line down** (scrolling the terminal up by one line when in the last line) and one line up again.

Should be done when the **prompt** is shown - or possibly as part of the prompt (try this first).

Regarding terminal codes and how/where to output: here's a more complex question - showing something in the line below:

[unix.SE: Display stuff below the prompt at a shell prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1022/display-stuff-below-the-prompt-at-a-shell-prompt)

[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)

Answer (score 0):

There's a 1px border by default around the grid of characters. You can increase this value by placing this in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`:

```
VteTerminal {
    -VteTerminal-inner-border: 1 1 5 1;  /* for vte <= 0.36 */
    padding: 1px 1px 5px 1px;            /* for vte >= 0.38 */
}
```

The four numbers are for top, right, bottom, left respectively.